# How to Decide/suggest Shard Key in For GridFS mongodb

Tags: mongodb

i have following document structure for files collection

```
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("51417514e4b06c14ef682854"), 
    "chunkSize" : NumberLong(262144), 
    "length" : NumberLong(1532), 
    "md5" : "067882a724de349d310e9a3a92e04617", 
    "filename" : "1363244267550media481B49589E924622B00E7846BCE3EEC7.tomcat1",
    "contentType" : "image/jpeg", 
    "uploadDate" : ISODate("2013-03-14T06:58:28.479Z"), 
    "aliases" : null, 
    "metadata" : {
        "name" : "1363244267550media481B49589E924622B00E7846BCE3EEC7.tomcat1",
        "customerId" : NumberLong(202), 
        "siteId" : NumberLong(103780),
        "userId" : NumberLong(102) 
    } 
}
```

and for Chunks collections i m inserting the files related data with "files_id"

Can any one suggest me the what are the shard Key should i to enable sharding in gridFS. with proper description

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In such gridfs environments, you have two choices. Sharding the file chunks or not. Sharding the chunks leads all shards having the at least one file chunk to be busy. Which is not good. So you have to save all chunks on one shard. And this is basically done by using **'files_id'** of the chunks collection as shard key.